# Collection that is set to indirect only is still visible when placed through geometry nodes

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes, visibility

I am trying to achieve that an object is set to indirect only in specific view layers in Blender 4.0.2 since I do not want to see the door when I'm looking at it directly or from a perspective, but I do want to see it when I'm looking at it from above or the side. Though this door collection is getting instanced in geometry nodes. From what I can tell this sadly doesn't work, since when I render the image it still appears.

[image: The render with the undesired end result where the door is still visible]

[image: A screenshot of the geometry nodes setup used to place the door in the room]

[image: A screen shot of the Blender outliner, focusing on a collection called S_Basic_Door_90x100 on which the collection is checked and the visibility, rendering and indirect only are enabled.]

Am I doing/understanding something wrong about how this works and is there perhaps a workaround for this?

Comment: No matter where your geometries come from, they are all contain within one object. That object has its own render settings. I don't think you can achieve what you presented that way.